# How to do a query based pagination in a MongoDB collection according to a unique attribute?

Tags: mongodb, pagination

I have a collection named `ranking` which documents look like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55dde5e4827ff4e65b684f94"), "round" : 0, "teamId" : "55a9c261a02911b85fdff231", "teamName" : "FORZA JUVE", "userId" : "55a9c209291bc40561cc97d2", "signupDate" : ISODate("2015-07-18T03:03:37Z"), "userName" : "Noé González Ramírez", "signupPoints" : 0, "lfPoints" : 559, "roundPoints" : [ 110, 99, 91, 65, 64, 61, 69 ], "roundRankings" : [ ], "ranking" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55dde591827ff4e65b6846d6"), "round" : 0, "teamId" : "55a58179f82921e922244402", "teamName" : "Dream ★ Team", "userId" : "55a5809fd18e541b2176412f", "signupDate" : ISODate("2015-07-14T21:35:27Z"), "userName" : "Fabio Dionicio López Lazcano", "signupPoints" : 0, "lfPoints" : 555, "roundPoints" : [ 105, 91, 108, 60, 53, 77, 61 ], "roundRankings" : [ ], "ranking" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55dde593827ff4e65b6847d3"), "round" : 0, "teamId" : "55a58889f82921e922245511", "teamName" : "Camel Toes", "userId" : "55a58868f82921e9222454b1", "signupDate" : ISODate("2015-07-14T22:08:40Z"), "userName" : "Luis Fridman Tabak", "signupPoints" : 0, "lfPoints" : 555, "roundPoints" : [ 74, 96, 99, 76, 69, 70, 71 ], "roundRankings" : [ ], "ranking" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55dde60a827ff4e65b6853d5"), "round" : 0, "teamId" : "55ac7ca61532c9284e2a89a7", "teamName" : "S.T.A.R.S.", "userId" : "55ac7be31532c9284e2a895c", "signupDate" : ISODate("2015-07-20T04:41:07Z"), "userName" : "Daniel Ivan Estudillo Lopez", "signupPoints" : 0, "lfPoints" : 555, "roundPoints" : [ 61, 94, 105, 73, 90, 50, 82 ], "roundRankings" : [ ], "ranking" : 4 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55dde5d2827ff4e65b684db3"), "round" : 0, "teamId" : "55a857b8fad3a3124ca72edf", "teamName" : "EFRASTEAM", "userId" : "55a8575dfad3a3124ca72ebd", "signupDate" : ISODate("2015-07-17T01:16:13Z"), "userName" : "EFRAÍN BARRIENTOS RODRÍGUEZ", "signupPoints" : 0, "lfPoints" : 549, "roundPoints" : [ 102, 89, 92, 58, 81, 60, 67 ], "roundRankings" : [ ], "ranking" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55dde5c1827ff4e65b684baa"), "round" : 0, "teamId" : "55a800a4ac9c9c3302be1dee", "teamName" : "Lombardi FC", "userId" : "55a722eac0dbc6e577489d34", "signupDate" : ISODate("2015-07-16T03:20:10Z"), "userName" : "J Alejandro Padilla", "signupPoints" : 0, "lfPoints" : 546, "roundPoints" : [ 103, 98, 65, 47, 77, 59, 97 ], "roundRankings" : [ ], "ranking" : 6 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55dde5a1827ff4e65b68485f"), "round" : 0, "teamId" : "55a5c2e88a5f0fd66b355ef6", "teamName" : "FC Barcelona", "userId" : "55a5c0458a5f0fd66b355d6f", "signupDate" : ISODate("2015-07-15T02:07:01Z"), "userName" : "Daniel Alvarez Nunez", "signupPoints" : 0, "lfPoints" : 545, "roundPoints" : [ 94, 101, 82, 63, 71, 68, 66 ], "roundRankings" : [ ], "ranking" : 7 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55dde55d827ff4e65b684197"), "round" : 0, "teamId" : "55a54fbfef67112c685cf78d", "teamName" : "RUCHINTER FC *", "userId" : "55a54f713711fed46621fb01", "signupDate" : ISODate("2015-07-14T18:05:37Z"), "userName" : "RAUL VERA LUGO", "signupPoints" : 0, "lfPoints" : 544, "roundPoints" : [ 84, 109, 87, 41, 84, 57, 82 ], "roundRankings" : [ ], "ranking" : 8 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55dde583827ff4e65b684661"), "round" : 0, "teamId" : "55a57327f82921e9222418ae", "teamName" : "SPARTA FC *", "userId" : "55a571b2f82921e9222413a2", "signupDate" : ISODate("2015-07-14T20:31:46Z"), "userName" : "Alejandro Padilla", "signupPoints" : 0, "lfPoints" : 544, "roundPoints" : [ 86, 98, 93, 29, 80, 65, 93 ], "roundRankings" : [ ], "ranking" : 9 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55dde592827ff4e65b684739"), "round" : 0, "teamId" : "55a59941b07aeb00512822d8", "teamName" : "Minions", "userId" : "55a59400d18e541b21766a0e", "signupDate" : ISODate("2015-07-14T22:58:08Z"), "userName" : "Carlos Zarate", "signupPoints" : 0, "lfPoints" : 541, "roundPoints" : [ 100, 91, 69, 66, 76, 68, 71 ], "roundRankings" : [ ], "ranking" : 10 }
```

As you can see they got a `ranking` attribute which is an integer, that attribute is NOT (and can not be) assigned on creation.

So I need to *obtain the whole documents with round set to 0, ordered by ranking in decrement order*. In other words I have to paginate the whole documents (they're about 300K).

I know there's an approach where you query looking for documents with `_id` greater than last result in previous page.

This is why I tried following indexes:

```
{ranking: 1, _id: 1, round: 1}
{ranking: 1,  _id: 1}
```

So first I query the first *n* elements at first page, for example:

```
db.ranking.find({round: 0}).sort({ranking: 1}).limit(3)
```

Which outputs:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55dde5e4827ff4e65b684f94"), "round" : 0, "teamId" : "55a9c261a02911b85fdff231", "teamName" : "FORZA JUVE", "userId" : "55a9c209291bc40561cc97d2", "signupDate" : ISODate("2015-07-18T03:03:37Z"), "userName" : "Noé González Ramírez", "signupPoints" : 0, "lfPoints" : 559, "roundPoints" : [ 110, 99, 91, 65, 64, 61, 69 ], "roundRankings" : [ ], "ranking" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55dde591827ff4e65b6846d6"), "round" : 0, "teamId" : "55a58179f82921e922244402", "teamName" : "Dream ★ Team", "userId" : "55a5809fd18e541b2176412f", "signupDate" : ISODate("2015-07-14T21:35:27Z"), "userName" : "Fabio Dionicio López Lazcano", "signupPoints" : 0, "lfPoints" : 555, "roundPoints" : [ 105, 91, 108, 60, 53, 77, 61 ], "roundRankings" : [ ], "ranking" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55dde593827ff4e65b6847d3"), "round" : 0, "teamId" : "55a58889f82921e922245511", "teamName" : "Camel Toes", "userId" : "55a58868f82921e9222454b1", "signupDate" : ISODate("2015-07-14T22:08:40Z"), "userName" : "Luis Fridman Tabak", "signupPoints" : 0, "lfPoints" : 555, "roundPoints" : [ 74, 96, 99, 76, 69, 70, 71 ], "roundRankings" : [ ], "ranking" : 3 }
```

And if then I try to get following page:

```
db.lineuppointsrecord.find({round: 0, _id: {$gt: ObjectId("55dde593827ff4e65b6847d3")}}).sort({ranking: 1}).limit(3)
```

That will incorrectly output:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55dde5e4827ff4e65b684f94"), "round" : 0, "teamId" : "55a9c261a02911b85fdff231", "teamName" : "FORZA JUVE", "userId" : "55a9c209291bc40561cc97d2", "signupDate" : ISODate("2015-07-18T03:03:37Z"), "userName" : "Noé González Ramírez", "signupPoints" : 0, "lfPoints" : 559, "roundPoints" : [ 110, 99, 91, 65, 64, 61, 69 ], "roundRankings" : [ ], "ranking" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55dde60a827ff4e65b6853d5"), "round" : 0, "teamId" : "55ac7ca61532c9284e2a89a7", "teamName" : "S.T.A.R.S.", "userId" : "55ac7be31532c9284e2a895c", "signupDate" : ISODate("2015-07-20T04:41:07Z"), "userName" : "Daniel Ivan Estudillo Lopez", "signupPoints" : 0, "lfPoints" : 555, "roundPoints" : [ 61, 94, 105, 73, 90, 50, 82 ], "roundRankings" : [ ], "ranking" : 4 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55dde5d2827ff4e65b684db3"), "round" : 0, "teamId" : "55a857b8fad3a3124ca72edf", "teamName" : "EFRASTEAM", "userId" : "55a8575dfad3a3124ca72ebd", "signupDate" : ISODate("2015-07-17T01:16:13Z"), "userName" : "EFRAÍN BARRIENTOS RODRÍGUEZ", "signupPoints" : 0, "lfPoints" : 549, "roundPoints" : [ 102, 89, 92, 58, 81, 60, 67 ], "roundRankings" : [ ], "ranking" : 5 }
```

First result is the doc with round 1 present at first page from initial query!

I know I could use skip and limit but, how should I perform the query in order of performance?

Comment: So you're basically trying to sort by round first then by rank? So you'll display all those in round 0 in ascending order(lets say 1-10), then you'll iterate to round 1 and again in ascending order by rank(1-10)? You're basically trying to sort on 2 different values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Page based on unique values**

If each ranking is unique in the collection, as in your example documents,  and every required document has a ranking, you could query each time using the last ranking of the previous results e.g.:

```
db.ranking.find({round: 0}).sort({ranking: 1}).limit(3)
db.ranking.find({round: 0, ranking : {$gt : 3}}).sort({ranking: 1}).limit(3)
db.ranking.find({round: 0, ranking : {$gt : 6}}).sort({ranking: 1}).limit(3)
```

If ranking is not unique in the collection, i.e. if there can be ties where multiple teams have the same ranking, this approach won't work, as it is dependant on the next ranking always being greater than the previous one. If you try to use it, you could end up skipping documents.

This solution can use the index `{ round: 1, ranking: 1 }`

**Range based paging**

If ranking is unique, always incremented by 1 and there are no gaps, you could even query by range as you know the rankings you expect:

```
db.ranking.find({round: 0, ranking : {$gte : 1, $lte: 3 }})
db.ranking.find({round: 0, ranking : {$gte : 4, $lte: 6 }})
db.ranking.find({round: 0, ranking : {$gte : 7, $lte: 9 }})
```

If ranking is not unique in the collection, you can still do this but would need to handle the fact that it might result in pages of varying size or even empty pages, especially for small page sizes.

This solution can also use the index `{ round: 1, ranking: 1 }`

**Paging over non-unique values**

For completeness, here is a query that will handle paging over non-unique rankings and is covered by an index. It needs to check that the ranking is greater, OR the ranking is the same and the _id is greater. I'd recommend the other solutions if possible as they are much simpler, both the index required and the query.

```
db.ranking.createIndex({round: 1, ranking: 1, _id: 1})

db.ranking.find({$or : [
       {round: 0, ranking : { $gt : 3}},
       {round: 0, ranking : 3, _id : { $gt : new ObjectId("55a9c261a02911b85fdff231")}}
    ]})
.sort({round:1, ranking: 1, _id: 1})
.limit(3)
```

Comment: Excellent response, thanks so much!!! I will use first approach as rankings are unique and already got `{round: 1, ranking: 1}` index.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort by multiple fields. You can sort first by round, then by rank. What this will do is it will first sort all of round 0 by rank, then next round 1 by rank, then round 2 by rank, etc, etc...

You just specify multiple fields in the sort object like so:

```
db.ranking.find({}).sort({round: 1, ranking: 1})
```

Then you can paginate like normal.

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned, you can (and should here) sort by multiple fields.

In your original query you have

```
.sort({ranking: 1})
```

Which leaves order of `_id` undefined. But you actually rely on its order! So, make it explicit.

```
.sort({ranking: 1, _id: 1})
```